# Retrieving items from a nested dictionary with a nested for loop fresults in KeyError

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I need to systematically access dictionaries that are nested within a list within a dictionary at the 3rd level, like this:

```
responses = {'1': {'responses': [{1st dict to be retrieved}, {2nd dict to be retrieved}, ...]},
             '2': {'responses': [{1st dict to be retrieved}, {2nd dict to be retrieved}, ...]}, ...}
```

I need to unnest and transform these nested dicts into dataframes, so the end result should look like this:

```
responses = {'1': df1,
             '2': df2, ...}
```

In order to achieve this, I built a for-loop in order to loop through all keys on the first level. Within that loop, I am using another loop to extract each item from the nested dicts into a new empty list called `responses_df`:

```
responses_dict = {}

for key in responses.keys():
    for item in responses[key]['responses']:
        responses_dict[key].update(item)
```

However, I get:

```
KeyError: '1'
```

The inner loop works if I use it individually on a key within the dict, but that doesn't really help me since the data comes from an API and has to be updated dynamically every few minutes in production.

The nex loop to transform the result into dataframes would look like this:

```
for key in responses_dict:
     responses_df[key] = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(responses_dict[key], orient='index')
```

But I haven't gotten to try that out since the first operation fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from collections import defaultdict      

responses_dict = defaultdict(dict) # instead of {}
```

Then your code will work.

Comment: This was by far the easiest solution. I had tried this before, but somehow it didn't work until now.

Answer (score 0):

In fact `responses_dict[key]` where `key=1` doesn't exist.

So when you simply do `print(responses_dict[key])` you get the same error, `1` is not a key of that `dict` and `update` is not used as it should be.

Try the following syntax :

```py
responses_dict = {}

for key in responses.keys():
    print(key)
    for item in responses[key]['responses']:
        responses_dict.update(key = item)
```

Comment: This only outputs the last item of the list within the last key, and the key is just called `key`: `{'key': {'...'}`, so somehow the update function isn't called correctly. It does print all the keys first though, so the problem is somewhere in the second loop.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using dictionaries while updating a dictionary.

If you update with an existing key, the value of that key will be updated. 
If you update with an new key-value pair, the pair will be added to that dictionary.

```
>>>d1 = {1: 10, 2:20}
>>>d1.update({1:20})
>>>d1
>>>{1: 20, 2:20}

>>>d1.update({3:30})
>>>d1
>>>{1: 20, 2:20, 3:30}
```

Try fixing your line with:

```
responses_dict = {}
for key in responses.keys():
    for item in responses[key]['responses']:
        responses_dict.update({key: item})
```

So basically, use dictionary to update a dictionary, more readable and easy.

Comment: Unfortunately this still only outputs the last item in list of the last key, as with other responses.

Comment: The code is exacly as suggested by you, the output looks like this: `{'key': {'...'}`. It's only one list item.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
responses = {'1': {'responses': [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'c': 3, 'd': 4}]},
             '2': {'responses': [{'e': 5}, {'f': 6}]}}

result = {k: pd.DataFrame(chain.from_iterable(v['responses'])) for k, v in responses.items()}

for df in result.values():
    print(df, end='\n\n')
```

Output:

```
   0
0  a
1  b
2  c
3  d

   0
0  e
1  f
```